# How to use SELECT/INSERT statement in snowflake UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where I need to create a UDF in snowflake but it has complex Select and Insert statements. But as per the documentation, SELECT statement cannot be used in UDF. Is there any possible workaround?

Comment: If you give us more specifics, we can give you a more specific answer. Sample data and expected results?

Comment: The standard purpose of a UDF is to perform calculations and ultimately return a value (or set of values) - it is not generally used to change data (insert, update, delete). If you want to code a business process then standard practice would be to use stored procedure, not a UDF

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that in UDF .
For eg:
create or replace function orders_for_product(prod_id varchar)
returns table (product_id varchar, quantity_sold numeric(11, 2))
as
$$
select product_id, quantity_sold
from orders
where product_id = prod_id
$$
;

Answer (score 0):

User-defined functions accept parameters, perform an operation(some calculation) and return the result of that operation as a value. The operations that are not available through the built-in, system-defined functions are generally defined using UDFs.

However, you can incorporate SELECT in the UDF as provided below and some examples of how a UDF can be used are provided in the link shared.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION profit()
  RETURNS NUMERIC(11, 2)
AS
  $$ 
SELECT SUM((retail_price - wholesale_price) * number_sold)
        FROM purchases
  $$
  ;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-overview.html#sql